# Embed in php file not able to src outside of its current directory in /WAMP

Tags: php, html, wamp

I need help solving a minor problem I have run into while creating a pdf embed page.

The goal is to click on an anchor tag which sets a Session variable with the directory of the pdf file (to be displayed). The problem I am having is that the src="[directory]" is not working for me. It does work if I hardcode a pdf that is in the current directory, but if i use a directory like "C:\folder\pdf.pdf" the src will not show up.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html style="display:inline;">
<body>

<div style="display: inline; position: relative; float: left; width: 69%">
<embed type="application/pdf" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['pdfLocation']?>" style="width: 100%; height:620px;"></embed>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, webservers cannot access data outside the web root (/var/www/htdocs, or whatever your webserver is set up for). Which makes sense, you don't want visitors from all over the world browsing your filesystem.  Try putting it in a subdirectory (./inc is common) of your web root.

Comment: thank you! still a novice at this